# How to solve below error for sp 2013 on premises setup

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, ad

I am setting sharepoint 2013 single server farm for training and learning purposes and while clicking on "Promote this server to a domain controller", i am getting error, please see below screenshots.Can someone please assist?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short,** The `forest root domain name` consists of two parts **`prefix.suffix`**, you are tried to set the `forest root domain name` to a single label domain name so you got this error!

Read more about [Assigning Domain Names](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/assigning-domain-names)

---

In your case (`Learning environment`), try to set `forest root domain name` as

```
 sp2013.local
```

> **Note:**  Installing the AD role on the same Standalone SharePoint server will work but it's recommended to install the **AD** role in
>   an independent server (VM) to avoid the performance issue.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, I will give that a try. Thanks for the note as well, I am currently in the learning phase, so part of my SharePoint admin training, i am going through the setup and all but will keep this in mind from a production environment.

Comment: Okay, Great @mdevm .  Please, don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you? Thanks!